# Angular unit test keyCode?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am developping an angular application.
I want to increase tests coverage on my project.
How can implement unit test in angular for this condition?
`[46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1`

Comment: You can pass any object with keyCode property to mock the function.

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1` means you are checking whether that keyCode is present in that array or not right.. You can do this:

```
it('should run the test'. () => {
  component.keyCode = 2 // Give a value which is not present in that array.
  spyOn(component, 'yourMethodWhereThatCodeIsThere').and.callThrough();
  component.yourMethodWhereThatCodeIsThere();
  expect(component.yourMethodWhereThatCodeIsThere).toHaveBeenCalled();
})

This should cover that line
```